# How to create a link to a given host using named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have this code :

```
<%= link_to 'Whatever', some_path(some_var) %>
```

This code is in an email view, so I would like to specify a host for the link.

I tried :

```
<%= link_to 'Whatever', some_path(some_var, :host => 'http://my.host') %>
```

This did not work, what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the url version of the helper did the trick :

```
<%= link_to 'Whatever', some_url(some_var, :host => 'http://my.host') %>
```

[Source](http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/1299774075/using-rails-3-route-helpers-outside-of-a)